# Repeat background image with Sprite

Tags: css, background, css-sprites

I've read about theses threads but I don't know how to find the answer.

The problem is (for body):

```
background: url('image1.png') top left repeat-x, 
        url('image2.png') bottom left repeat-x, 
        #eeeeee;
```

This works.

How can I to set these images in a sprites? Because I can get the image form sprite as:

```
  background-position: -211px -0px; width: 8px; height: 110px;
```

But I need to get image1.png or image2.png from sprite and I also need to repeat the images on the x. Something like:

```
background: url('image1.png') "-211px -0px; width: 8px; height: 110px" repeat-x, 
        url('image2.png') "-211px -0px; width: 8px; height: 110px" repeat-x, 
        #eeeeee;
```

That I know in this way is not possible.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried this before and I don't think it is possible, as of yet. When you use a sprite image, you specify its `x, y, width, height` values. With a repeating image, you do not, so I think it is best to have 2 separate images, `sprite.png` `bg.jpg` for example. I know it is an extra `HTTP` request, but it is a very small one. There is an attribute called `-image-rect` but it is not vastly used.

Comment: Something similar:
http://www.phpied.com/background-repeat-and-css-sprites/

But in this case, is for 3 divs, and I neew for a body...

Thanks Ashley

Comment: This technique only allows you to `repeat-x` or `repeat-y`. if you specified `-x` then your other sprites must be underneath and if you specify `-y` then they will need to be next to it, if you get what I mean

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct:

```
background: url('image1.png') "-211px -0px; width: 8px; height: 110px" repeat-x, 
    url('image2.png') "-211px -0px; width: 8px; height: 110px" repeat-x, 
    #eeeeee;
```

Instead you should write this:

```
background: url('image1.png') repeat-x -211px -0px / 8px 110px, 
    url('image2.png') repeat-x -211px -0px / 8px 110px;
background-color:  #eeeeee;
```

But you'll need 2 separate images, you will not be able do it with a sprite.